# Annotation processor only processing a modified class after first run

Tags: java, eclipse, class, annotation-processing

I'm  developing an annotation processor.

When the processor project is compiled as a .jar, the processing happens on all classes of my second project which uses the processor (also happens when I use Project->Clean... on Eclipse). But when I change one class, and save it, on my second project the processing happens only in this class.

The problem is that my processor must to get the root elements of all classes, but, when it runs only in one class, it can get only the root element of this class.

Any ideas about how to get all the root elements of the project?

Comment: Are you only using the processor under eclipse, or are you using in a build as well?

Comment: I think it's running under Eclipse only. I don't know the other way. It's configurated, in Eclipse, in 
Properties->Java Compiler->Annotation Processing.

Comment: Eclipse performs incremental compilation which makes bulk annotation processing a bit harder.  I know that some projects keep a file of known roots and use that as input to process all the roots during annotation processing.  Personally, I prefer to run a mvn clean install or similar build outside of the IDE to handle annotation processing.

Comment: I think I could store the modified classes on a static variable so that I can access all of them at any time. But how to deal with a class remotion. Is there a way to know if a class is being removed from the project? I don't know much about mvn install os similar. Could you give me a reference about this?

Answer (score 0):

I know, its an old question, but I stumbled upon this problem right now and I also found a solution. In eclipse (I am using Mars), right-click on project -> properties -> JavaCompiler -> Annotation Processing -> Factory Path -> Advanced... -> Run this container's processors in batch mode

[image]